# Gradle processResources expand on different projects modules

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, environment-variables

i'm trying to get a project.version so i wrote `project2` gradle before codes

```
processResources {
   def props = ['version': project.properties.get('version')]
   filesMatching("**/MyConfiguration.kt") {
      expand(props)
   }
}
```

the `MyConfiguration.kt` file located `project1` but the code return null

so i fixed codes like below

```
processResources {
   def props = ['version': project.properties.get('version')]
   expand(props)
}
```

then that codes return right value

maybe the problem is filesMatching input another module file?

Answer (score 0):

i missed `filesMatching` input

need to setup `.properties` or `.yaml` (get project.properties this scope)

Comment: Its great to see you have found the solution, please include some references or explanation on how you completed the setup to make this a good contribution for the rest of the community.

Comment: Before i wrote on build.gradle processResources { project.properties.get('version') .. filesMatching expand ... }
But i missed the fileMatching argument file path so when i fixed it, it worked
Anyway currently i'm using springBoot { buildInfo() }